# Redirect from .net aspx to html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, response.redirect

I am on a .net 4 aspx page and I simply want to redirect to an html page that is located in the same site location.  When I try to do the following, I get the error {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

```
Response.Redirect("ContractorEnvironment.html");
```

I have to use an aspx page for logging in but my application is on a single html page.

Comment: That's not the error.  Are you sure you aren't seeing the normal ThreadAbort from `Redirect()`?

Comment: did you Add the root path in your application.

Comment: Yes, I tried adding the full path.

Comment: Let me check on the TreadAbort and thanks for the tip

Comment: SLaks was right on!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

SLaks answered the question:

I have to use a custom login process and needed a try/catch to manage errors but if login is successful, I was redirecting within the try.  Simply moved the redirect outside the try.